# setup nox (or genymotion )as android emulator for vscode flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

for some reason, I don't want to install android studio(one of them is I don't have enough space for now) but instead, I want to work with vscode and nox(or genymotion). and my question is: Is it possible to connect vscode and an (android and ios) emulator to see the result? in other words, I want to connect the nox as an emulator to vscode and see the result inside of it.

Comment: Nothing is impossible if you find the right extensions or write your own ones. So, instead of asking for recommendations (which is off topic), you should focus more on what search engines can guide you and how to write your own VS Code extensions to fill the gaps. Contact the developers of the Flutter extension, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter and they can guide you as well.

Comment: Common red-flagged questions like "how to" and "is it possible" should be replaced by more specific questions such as "I tried something but it breaks this way". If you are tasked (and paid) to do something, don't try to misuse kindness of others here.

Comment: if you run your emulator and execute `flutter devices` command, what do you see on the terminal console then?

Comment: @pskink just default devices: windows, chrome, edge

Comment: so it seems that your emulator does not support flutter, what you see if you run `adb devices`?

Comment: @pskink the result is: "List of devices attached". but nothing was added to the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio take too much space and even my computer also become hot when open Android studio. But what I did I installed Android studio and Android emulator but I don't use Android studio rather I use VScode.
So as far as I know you need Android studio to install emulator then you can use VScode with it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out how I can connect Genymotion to the VS Code(without Installing Android Studio).in total SDK manager wasn't installed on my laptop, so at first, I installed it. and then

2. Platform Tools (ADB & Fastboot)
3. Install Platform
4. Add System Image
5. Install Build Tools

---

but wait I just name the steps I've done. you can follow this article on [this link](https://dev.to/shivams136/how-to-install-android-sdk-without-android-studio-ff2) to get more details.
and finally, instead of installing an emulator, I used Genymotion with Flutter in VS Code, which you can follow in this article to get more information. [Click here](https://olalekanagbaje.medium.com/using-genymotion-emulator-with-flutter-in-vs-code-without-android-studio-84994a1071f5)